# moving button in footer

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to place these buttons in the middle of the footer without changing the size of the buttons. I presume I need to use ui-grid-(a,b,c..) but whenever I do so, the button sizes expand to completely fill in whatever percentage the grid in the function I choose.

my code:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" >
    <a data-role="button" data-icon="plus">CS</a>
    <a data-role="button" data-icon="plus">GH</a>
</div>
```

Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/liondancer/rKPfe/

Comment: Wouldn't just ```align="center"``` attribute in the div do the trick?

Comment: @Kazzkiq reply to this question with an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `align` HTML attribute to center them, like this:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" align="center">
    <a data-role="button" data-icon="plus">CS</a>
    <a data-role="button" data-icon="plus">GH</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS selector. Add this to your CSS in that jsfiddle

```
div[data-role="footer"] {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didnt quite work but @Kazzkiq helped me out! thank you for your input!

Comment: The <div> align attribute is not supported in HTML5, which is why I used CSS in my answer instead, but I'm glad you got your answer :)